# how to fix libarchive compile error on VLC 3.0.16

Tags: macos, vlc, macos-big-sur

Running Intel mac on big sur 11.4 and trying to compile VLC from source 3.0.16. Am getting the following error - can anyone lend insights as to how to fix?

```
config.status: executing mkdirs commands
cd libarchive && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make install
build/autoconf/install-sh -c -d libarchive/test
cat ./libarchive/test/test_*.c | grep '^DEFINE_TEST' > libarchive/test/list.h
build/autoconf/install-sh -c -d tar/test
cat ./tar/test/test_*.c | grep '^DEFINE_TEST' > tar/test/list.h
build/autoconf/install-sh -c -d cpio/test
cat ./cpio/test/test_*.c | grep '^DEFINE_TEST' > cpio/test/list.h
cat ./cat/test/test_*.c | grep '^DEFINE_TEST' > cat/test/list.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  install-am
  CC       libarchive/archive_read_support_filter_lz4.lo
libarchive/archive_read_support_filter_lz4.c:564:23: error: implicit declaration of function 'LZ4_decompress_safe' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                uncompressed_size = LZ4_decompress_safe(read_buf + 4,
                                    ^
libarchive/archive_read_support_filter_lz4.c:591:23: error: implicit declaration of function 'LZ4_decompress_safe_withPrefix64k' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                uncompressed_size = LZ4_decompress_safe_withPrefix64k(
                                    ^
libarchive/archive_read_support_filter_lz4.c:701:19: error: implicit declaration of function 'LZ4_COMPRESSBOUND' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        if (compressed > LZ4_COMPRESSBOUND(LEGACY_BLOCK_SIZE)) {
                         ^
libarchive/archive_read_support_filter_lz4.c:714:8: error: implicit declaration of function 'LZ4_decompress_safe' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        ret = LZ4_decompress_safe(read_buf + 4, state->out_block,
              ^
4 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [libarchive/archive_read_support_filter_lz4.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [.libarchive] Error 2
System123:build USER5$
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by downloading the latest libarchive tar, going through the build process and tossing resulting entire libarchive dir into the contrib/contrib-x86_64-apple-darwin20/libarchive (renamed without the version).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).